# Primera coincidencia de datos repetidos SQL

Tags: sql, tsql

Tengo 3 tablas:

- Productos
- FamiliaProductos
- Agrupacion

En la tabla `Productos` tengo datos así (id del producto, su nombre y su familia)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla `FamiliaProductos` viene lo clasificación de cada producto (es un producto de cafetería, es un pollo, es una chuleta, etc)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla Agrupacion es casi lo mismo que Familia... solo que se ubica en otra base de datos y tiene las siguientes caracteristicas iguales a Familia....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestion es esta, estoy armando un query que me saque de la tabla "`FamiliaProductos`" los primeros 3 digitos de la columna "`Familia`" (en este caso 005) y saque igual los primeros 3 digitos de la tabla "`IDAgrupacionW`" de la tabla "`Agrupacion`", y decir, el Pollo entero con ID 123445, tiene el ID_Categoria (de la tabla Agrupacion)=12

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.ID_Agrupacion) AS ID_A, SP.idProducto, FP.CodigoFamilia, FP.DescripcionFamiliaProductos, LEFT(FP.CodigoFamilia, 3) AS CODIGO,  A.Agrupacion
FROM Productos SP
INNER FamiliasProductos FP ON FP.CodigoFamilia = SP.Familia 
INNER JOIN dbo.Agrupacion A ON LEFT(A.IDAgrupacionW,3)=LEFT(FP.CodigoFamilia,3) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
WHERE IdProducto IN (XXXXXXX)
ORDER BY SP.IdProducto
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el query me sale el resultado asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo modificar el query para que me traiga solo la "primera" coincidencia que encuentre?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero la estructura de los datos para el ejemplo. Solo he puesto una fila, puesto que para la misma, es suficiente.

```
Create table productos (idProducto int, NombreCompleto varchar(100), Familia varchar(20));

Create table FamiliasProductos (idFamiliaProducto int, CodigoFamilia varchar(20), DescripcionFamiliaProductos varchar(200), idClaseProducto int);

Create Table Agrupacion (IDAgrupacionW varchar(200), otro varchar(100));

Go

Insert into productos (idProducto, NombreCompleto, Familia)
values
('15001801','Pollo','900904900900');

Insert into FamiliasProductos(idFamiliaProducto, CodigoFamilia, DescripcionFamiliaProductos, idClaseProducto)
Values (1,'900904900900', 'FamiliaPollos',null);

Insert into Agrupacion (IDAgrupacionW, otro)
values
('900PollosA',null),
('900PollosB',null);

Go
```

Con la consulta actual, esto resuelve dos filas.

```
Select Distinct 
       a.IDAgrupacionW As id_a
     , sp.idproducto
     , fp.codigofamilia
     , fp.descripcionfamiliaproductos
     , Left(fp.codigofamilia, 3) As codigo
    -- , a.agrupacion
       From productos As sp
            Inner Join familiasproductos As fp On fp.codigofamilia = sp.familia
            Inner Join dbo.agrupacion As a On Left(a.idagrupacionw, 3) = Left(fp.codigofamilia, 3) Collate modern_spanish_ci_as
Order By sp.idproducto;
```

[image: Resultado]

**Una Solución**

Consiste en utilizar el operador `apply` para traer solo un valor. En función del escenario, sería o `Cross Apply`, o `Outer Apply` (equivalentes a Inner Join o Outer Join).

```
Select Distinct 
       fn.idagrupacionw As id_a
     , sp.idproducto
     , fp.codigofamilia
     , fp.descripcionfamiliaproductos
     , Left(fp.codigofamilia, 3) As codigo
     
       From productos As sp
            Join familiasproductos As fp On fp.codigofamilia = sp.familia
            Cross apply (
            Select top(1) * from dbo.Agrupacion a
                Where 
                    Left(a.idagrupacionw, 3) = Left(fp.codigofamilia, 3) Collate modern_spanish_ci_as
        ) fn
Order By sp.idproducto;
```

[image: Resultado 2]

La gracia, está en que en el conjunto ´fn´ en su definición, aplicamos un top(1) a la tabla `agrupación` y esta la relacionamos con el conjunto externo `FamiliasProducto` a través de su alias.

Existen otras posibilidades de realizar la query, que te pueden dar mejoras en los tiempos de ejecución.

[Subquerys correlativas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/07/06/subquery-correlativa-y-otras-formas-de-conseguirlo/)

[Operador Apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/)

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Gracias